# Commenting on a LinkedIn post using REST API returning 500

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a linkedin company page.I am trying to post a comment on an already existed post of that page via Linkedin Rest API. 
Below are the request details :

HTTP METHOD : POST

URL : https://api.linkedin.com/v2/socialActions/urn:li:activity:{activity-id}/comments

HEADERS : Authorization, Content-Type

BODY :

```
{"actor": "urn:li:organizationBrand:<org id>",
"message": {
    "attributes": [],
    "text": "This is a comment"
}}
```

The above request is throwing me the below error :

```
{"message": "com.linkedin.restli.client.RestLiResponseException: Response status 500, serviceErrorMessage: Error creating comment",
"status": 500}
```

The same request works for me for another linkedin company page. Can you please help me on finding what the issue is?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing at Sprout Social. Commenting as a company started to fail intermittently around 2018-05-26 and now fails every time. Seems to be happening on the v1 api as well: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50694581/linkedin-v1-update-comments-as-company-api-throws-500-error-code

Comment: I reported this bug to LinkedIn and they fixed it, it should be working now.

Comment: @Rob seed Thanks for the information.It is working now