# Linkedin V1 update-comments-as-company api throws 500 error code

Tags: api, linkedin-api

We are using Linkedin v1 api `update-comments-as-company` endpoint to post comments on behalf of company page managed by the user. Nowadays this endpoint throws 500 error response while trying to add comment.

Example request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxx" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "x-li-format: json" 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/12345/updates/key=UPDATE-c12345-640455667889990765/update-comments-as-company' --data '{"comment": "Posting as a company!"}'
```

Response:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Internal service error",
  "requestId": "OBVNKWRJDC",
  "status": 500,
  "timestamp": 1528183732917
}
```

Kindly help me to resolve this.

Comment: Related question using the v2 api: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50584614/commenting-on-a-linkedin-post-using-rest-api-returning-500

Comment: Do not send authorization header, use query parameter instead. Pass your access token through oauth2_access_token parameter

Comment: @NitinAgarwal sending token in parameter does not solve this issue. I have tried it also.